# How can I pass routes in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to pass routes to my Next.js app but it's returning an error, I've looked everywhere but I can't find the answer.

_App.tsx

```js
import Routes from './Routes'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <Index/>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

Routes.tsx

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import { SideBar } from './components/sideBar'

const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<SideBar />}/>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Routes
```

My error:

ReferenceError: document is not defined

Comment: **"Next.js has a file-system based router built on the concept of pages"** you don't need to use `react-router-dom` with next.js. Read the documentation.

Comment: Exactly you don't need react-router-dom with nextJS. It is managed inside pages

Comment: I'd recommend a read through https://nextjs.org/docs/migrating/from-react-router.

Answer (score 0):

you can Routes like this

```
<BrowserRouter>
 <Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={< Home />} />
  <Route path="/yourComponentsPage" element={< yourComponent/>} />
 </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

regards